# Trying to set up jQuery File Upload to show the picture that was just uploaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm following Railscasts Episode #381 to set up jQuery File Upload to upload files to the server on Rails 3.

Right I have it fully functional using jQuery File Upload + Paperclip.

Works fine. But I don't quite understand how to show the pictuers that just were uploaded without reloading the page.

The author of RailsCast says "just change the controller so it looks like this"

```
  def create
    @picture = Picture.create(params[:picture])
  end
```

(did that)

"and then make a create.js.erb template with following code"

```
<% if @picture.new_record? %>
    alert("Failed to upload picture");
<% else %>
    $("body").append("<% j render(@picture) %>");
<% end %>
```

(I don't understand to which folder I have to put it. Tried into app/views/pictures/ but it is not being triggered).

So I guess the question is - How do I trigger a "create.js.erb" when new picture is submitted.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

solved it like so:

```
<% if @picture.new_record? %>
    alert("Failed to upload picture");
<% else %>
    $("table").append('<tr><td><%= image_tag @picture.file.url(:small) %></td></tr>');
<% end %>
```